# How would I change file permissions if the file name has a space in it in linux

Tags: files, rename, filenames

I would like to know how would I rename and change file permissions of a file that contains a space in the name on Linux.

**Example**

The name of my file is: **my file**

I have tried `mv my%20file my_file`

I have also tried `chown -R 755 my%20file`

but both of these don't work!

Comment: I saw that post but i didn't know how to access bash script so i never worked for me.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. OP appears to be working at his terminal, not with a Bash script.

Comment: I agree with @Torger597 -- the dupe is far too complex for a non-scripting user to find intelligible, whereas this one is simple and concise.

Comment: That's correct guys what I was looking for was a simple solution and both answers below from **@Gnouc** as well as **@Michael Kohne** was the solution to my question. Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote file name:

```
rm 'my file' my_file
```

or escape space character:

```
rm my\ file my_file
```

Comment: when i do this it tells me Device or resource busy, but im not doing anything with the deveice

Answer (score 5):

You have to quote or escape the filename. In Bash (the default shell in most distros), you can either use quote marks to enclose the entire name, or a backslash to escape the one space.

```
rm "my file"
rm my\ file
```